# how to store BigInteger values in sybase 12 database?

Tags: java, database, types, sybase, biginteger

I use sybase 12 and java 7 with hibernate.
I want to store BigInteger values in the database. **What should be the type of the column?**

```
BigInteger b=new BigInteger("5779854559457802579079");
```

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Anywhere 12, or Sybase ASE 12?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQLAnywhere 12, Use the [**`Unsigned BigInt`**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbreference/bigint.html) datatype in to store the BigInteger values which range from:

0 to 18446744073709551615 (unsigned).

According to this [link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-837) there is no `BigInt` for Sybase ASE versions prior to 15.0.  Use `Numeric(19,0)` for BigInt type.

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify it, and fix the link to the documentation.

Comment: I get the following error when using `Numeric(19,0)`
`com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Domain error during implicit conversion of VARBINARY value '¬?' to a NUMERIC field.`

Answer (score 0):

change `BigInteger` to `BigDecimal`

Comment: Change it where, exactly?